# Issue with hubspot and bootstrap theme

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, themes, hubspot

We have created a new theme in bootstrap and applied a new theme to our blog on HUBSPOT. There is an issue when we resize window to responsive dimensions theme get stuck and scroll bar disappears around **600px**.

I can't move page up or down need help with this issue why theme get stuck in the middle and scroll bar disappears.

Theme link: [**blog.homearena.co.uk/hanewdesign**](http://blog.homearena.co.uk/hanewdesign)

Answer (score 0):

In HomeArena-style.min.css you've this code:

```
@media (max-width: 899px)
#site-wrapper{
 overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

It should be

```
@media (max-width: 899px)
#site-wrapper{
 overflow-y: scroll !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Height as Auto;

```
#site-wrapper{ height:auto}
```

If not works then kindly tell me